# Using includes to join two models in Rails and using the search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im a real noob at Rails.  Im actually a Business Analyst trying to teach myself code so i can work with Devs a lot closer at work.  I am having issues with retrieving fields from models.

I have two modals User and CricketClub Adverts, these can be seen below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

    #validates_presence_of   :picture
    #validates_integrity_of  :picture
    #validates_processing_of :picture

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :cricket_club_advert
  has_many :application
end
```

and

```
class CricketClubAdvert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :application

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

In my controller I have the following code:

```
@adverts = User.includes(:cricket_club_advert)
```

In my view i have the following:

```
<% @adverts.each do |advert| %>    
      <!-- Feed Entry -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-2 columns small-3">
        <%= image_tag(advert.picture_url) %>
        </div>
        <div class="large-10 columns">
          <h4> <%= link_to advert.cricket_club_advert.title, cricket_club_advert_path(advert.cricket_club_advert.id) %></h4>
 <%= truncate(strip_tags(advert.cricket_club_advert.description), length: 250) %> 
          <ul class="inline-list">
            <li><a href="">More</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
          <hr>  

      <!-- End Feed Entry -->
<% end %>
```

According to the documentation I have used the calls right, but i get this error:

> undefined method `title' forCricketClubAdvert::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007feca33270c0>

I cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really do here is you're iterating over `users` and its `adverts`. So your variable name is quite misleading, it should be:

```
@users = User.includes(:cricket_club_adverts)
```

and in your view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  # ...
  # ... here the iteration over adverts starts:
  <% user.cricket_club_adverts.each do |advert| %>
    # ...
  <% end %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

BTW note the plural form - if you use `has_many` association, you should name your assiciations in plural.

Comment: Sorry i should of explained more of what i am trying to do. i also want to display the User avatar next to the clubs adverts.  I am using carrierwave to manage uploads, will this still work?

Comment: @Glenn Coyle So you want to iterate over users, right?

Comment: @Merek Lipka - thanks that looks like it works, got a few formatting issues but thats more with my HTML.  Ive also changed the association in the modal file to better reflect convention.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of : 
@adverts = User.includes(:cricket_club_advert)
Use :
@adverts = User.includes(:cricket_club_adverts)
```

Because, one user has got many cricket_club_adverts (has - many relation)

```
first_advert = @adverts.first
cricket_advert = first_advert.cricket_club_adverts.first 
 #as one user can have many cricket_club_adverts and each 
 #cricket_club_advert will have title, id, description attributes.

hence title, id, description can be fetched by:
cricket_advert.title  #fetch the title
cricket_advert.id  #fetch the id
cricket_advert.description  # fetch the description.
```